# Javascript: content editable when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a table where i can edit the content in button click event its working but, only the **top most** row is functioning

Here's my Code

```
  <tr  id="tr">
    <td class="text-center" >
    <input type="hidden" value="' . $row['LOG_ID'] . '" id="logid" name="logid" >
      <label class="col-large-2 control-label text-sm " id="lab1" > ' . $row['DATE'] . '</label><input type="text" hidden id="datepicker" placeholder="Date" value="' . $row['DATE'] . '">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <label class="col-large-2 control-label text-sm  " id="lab2"> ' . $row['W_IN'] . ' </label> <input type="text" hidden id="w_in" value="' . $row['W_IN'] . '">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <label class="col-large-2 control-label text-sm" id="lab3"> ' . date("H:i:s", strtotime($row['W_OUT'])) . ' </label><input type="text" hidden id="w_out" value="' . $row['W_OUT'] . '">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <label class="col-large-2 control-label text-sm" id="lab4"> ' . $row['O_IN'] . ' </label><input type="text" id="o_in" hidden value="' . $row['O_IN'] . '">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <label class="col-large-2 control-label text-sm" id="lab5"> ' . $row['O_OUT'] . ' </label><input type="text" id="o_out" hidden value="' . $row['O_OUT'] . '">
    </td>
     <td class="text-sm text-center">
      <a  href="#" title="Save DTR" data-tooltip="true" hidden data-placement="bottom" id="saves" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a  href="#" title="Delete DTR" data-tooltip="true" data-placement="bottom" id="edit" onclick="myFunction(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a  href="#" title="Delete DTR" data-tooltip="true" data-placement="bottom" id="delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;

     </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onmousedown and onmouseup events for the button.

`onmousedown="element.contentEditable=true;" onmouseup="element.contentEditable=false;"`